# how can i get true\false output in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server-2005

i have this values in my table:

```
id
-----    
1    
2
null
3
4
null
5
```

Now I want to run a command similar to the following command:

```
select id==null from table
```

And the output should be as follows:

```
id
-----    
false
false
true
false
false
true
false
```

How do?

Comment: try using case using condition id IS NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CASE expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
SELECT id, 
       CASE WHEN id IS NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS id_Description
FROM dbo.Table1
```